# ¿Como realizar una consulta a una base de datos que no sea sensible a mayusculas/minusculas?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

Tengo una consulta del tipo:

```
select id,nombre,apellido from persona where apellido = 'Perez'
```

Como hago para que me retorne lo mismo que si yo hiciera

```
select id,nombre,apellido from persona where apellido = 'PeReZ'
```

o cualquier otra forma de escribir Perez con mayúsculas y minúsculas?
La consulta la hago a través de un PreparedStatement en Java, seteando el parámetro 'Perez', no se si tiene algo que ver.

Utilizo el motor de Postgresql

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La mejor solución depende de que tanto control tienes sobre la base de datos.

La peor solución seria cuando no tienes ni control ni certeza del motor, en ese caso podrias usar algo así.

```
SELECT id, nombre, apellido FROM persona WHERE upper(apellido) = upper('PeReZ')
```

Si no puedes cambiar la definición de las columnas, pero estas seguro que el motor es postgres, puedes hacer algo así

```
SELECT id, nombre, apellido FROM persona WHERE apellido ILIKE 'PeReZ'
```

Si puedes cambiar la definición de la columna en la tabla puedes definir persona como citext. Y a partir de postgres 12 tambien puedes usar collations

Answer (score 0):

Hola solo tienes q cambiar de enfoque el problema es muy sencillo, necesitas una funcion que convierta a (minisculas o mayusculas o solo la primera mayuscula, etc) todo tu texto antes de enviarla a la base de datos, por ejemplo a minusculas en Java el codigo seria

```js
let txt = "PeREz"

txt.toLowerCase()   

console.log(txt)
```

https://www.w3schools.com/java/ref_string_tolowercase.asp